# leer lista y hacer loop recorriendola toda (PYTHON)

Tags: python, lista, read

Estoy haciendo un programilla para el juego DIABLO 2, para que cada vez que caiga al suelo una runa, la coja, mediante pyautogui, lo que no sé cómo hacer es un loop que acabe cuando la lista esté completamente leída, es decir, que compruebe que ninguna de las imágenes de la lista está, entonces que finalice..

Ya que estoy, sería posible hacer esto pero leyendo la lista desde un archivo .txt ? (O otro formateo no es necesario que sea .txt

Muchas gracias, estoy aprendiendo y se me escapa esto..

```
 def nav_to_image(image, clicks, off_x=0, off_y=0):
 position = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen(image[0+1], confidence=.9)

 if position is None:
     print ("No rune found, ")
     return 0
 else:
    pyautogui.moveTo(position, duration=.3)
    sleep(0.5)
    pyautogui.leftClick()
```

image = ['images/jah.png', 'images/ohm.png', 'images/mal.png', 'images/ber.png', 'images/cham.png', 'images/ist.png',  ]

```
if image[] < len(image):
    sleep(2)
    nav_to_image(image, 1)
    image = image + [1]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para recorrer tu lista puedes usar un `for` y así recorrer cada uno de los elementos

```
images = ['images/1.png', 'images/2.png',..., 'images/n.png']
for image in images:
    # Aqui el codigo que quieres que se ejecute por imagen
```

Sobre lo segundo de leerlo desde un archivo se me ocurre usar un archivo de texto con los valores separados por comas y ya solo asignarlo a una variable

```
with open('archivo.txt') as lista:
    images = lista.read().split(',')
```

Ya todo junto se veria algo asi

```
with open('archivo.txt') as lista:
    images = lista.read().split(',')
    for image in images:
        sleep(2)
        nav_to_image(image, 1)
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, ambos códigos me han servido perfectamente, un saludo muy grande y gracias de nuevo!

Comment: @Zks la forma de decir gracias aquí es marcando la respuesta como aceptada, eso recompensa a ambos :D

Comment: Gracias Christian, ya está hecho, no tenía idea de ello! Un saludo